# Foreign key across multiple databases

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two databases: *accounts* and *company_x*.
In both db I have a table *users*.

**accounts.users**

```
user_id - pimary key, auto increment
first_name
last_name
time_zone
etc.
```

**company_x.users**

```
user_id - primary keu, auto increment
global_user_id
first_name
last_name
```

I want the following: when in `accounts.users` `first_name` or `last_name` changes to update `company_x.users`.

I know this way data is redundant (I store `first_name` and `last_name` in two places, but I decided not to make queries across databases).

How to set up a foreign key in this situation to automatically update the `company_x.users` table.

I can't simply create a foreign key from `company_x.users_first_name` to `accounts.users_last_name` because last_names aren't unique.

Thanks!

Comment: instead of this redundant data, you can keep the `first_name` & `last_name` in the accounts.users table and create a view in company_x.users, so you don't need to write cross-database queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a [composite foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240621/623041):

```
FOREIGN KEY (first_name, last_name)
  REFERENCES accounts.users (first_name, last_name)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Although, as [@Furqan comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262362/foreign-key-across-multiple-databases/12262441#comment16440440_12262362), there are probably better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried exactly what you are suggesting, but I got a "Foreign key incorrectly formed" error, because of wrong typo. Now this is working fine. I will make some tests also with views.
Thanks @Furqan for suggestion!