# Using concat with date turns search case sensitive

Tags: mysql, concatenation

The issue: 
Query concat on date column turns search case sensitive. When date column removed from concat the search is not case sensitive and returns the expected result set. This is happening in DEV but not QA environment.

Both environments have the same Server, Database and Connection collation settings, latin1_swedish_ci, but are different Mysql versions `(DEV:5.1.39; QA:5.1.61)`.

The table attributes in each environment (engine, charset) are the same: `InnoDB` and `latin1`.

`QRY:`

```
 select contact_id, lastname, firstname, dob
 from contact
 where concat(lastname,' ',firstname,' ',dob) = 'styles furious 1988-06-18';
```

We need the query to be case insensitive.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your dev server isn't >= v5.5.3?  The resultant character set of `CONCAT()` expressions comprising numeric arguments changed from binary to non-binary in that version.  You can explicitly transcode using `CAST()` if necessary.  Also, why not `WHERE lastname = 'styles' AND firstname = 'furious' AND dob = '1988-06-18'`?

Comment: Confirmed the MySQL versions. Ahh, well the table structure stores each value but outlying keys are on the concatenated string - so the string is being passed from child tables and checked by concating the values in the parent - if you guys are driving down the road and see me mowing the lawn, just run me over - pleas...

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a [composite foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12240621).

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, why are you using `CONCAT()` anyway, when you could just split the string at the client and do [this](http://www.sqlize.com/NHA5nYe5IG)?

```mysql
select contact_id, lastname, firstname, dob
from contact
where lastname = 'styles' and firstname = 'furious' and dob = '1988-06-18'
```

As long as the `lastname` and `firstname` columns are both [non-binary and using a case-insensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html), this query should be case insensitive.  It should also be *much* more efficient, if you have indexes on those columns.

Anyway, if you absolutely *insist* on using `CONCAT()`, you could always force the result to have the right type and collation, [like this](http://www.sqlize.com/v7BJ7VP783):

```mysql
select contact_id, lastname, firstname, dob
from contact
where
  convert(concat(lastname, ' ', firstname, ' ', dob) using latin1)
    collate latin1_general_ci = 'styles furious 1988-06-18';
```

However, that's really ugly and inefficient, and you shouldn't even consider using it in production unless you really have no other options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the upper function both around the concat and around the string so that you're comparing the upper case versions of both?

As far as I'm aware the = will always be case sensitive (I'm pretty new to mysql myself so aren't 100% on this but I'd expect it to be the case). Is it possible that there's some other difference between the environments (the data being passed in the tables or the value being compared to in the query) that would cause it to return a row?